# Django-Celery: djkombu_queue table no created

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery

**EDIT 2**
If someone can just post what the schema is supposed to be, I'd be more than happy! I just need to know the table names and column names!

I'm following along this tutorial:

http://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2014/06/23/scheduling-tasks-celery/

I've pip installed django-celery successfully.

```
#settings.py
import djcelery
djcelery.setup_loader()
BROKER_URL = 'django://'

INSTALLED_APPS = (
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'charts',
'social.apps.django_app.default',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'djcelery',
'kombu.transport.django',
)
```

When I run `python manage.py syncdb`:

```
Creating tables ...
Creating table django_admin_log
Creating table auth_permission
Creating table auth_group_permissions
Creating table auth_group
Creating table auth_user_groups
Creating table auth_user_user_permissions
Creating table auth_user
Creating table django_content_type
Creating table django_session
Creating table social_auth_usersocialauth
Creating table social_auth_nonce
Creating table social_auth_association
Creating table social_auth_code
Creating table celery_taskmeta
Creating table celery_tasksetmeta
Creating table djcelery_intervalschedule
Creating table djcelery_crontabschedule
Creating table djcelery_periodictasks
Creating table djcelery_periodictask
Creating table djcelery_workerstate
Creating table djcelery_taskstate
```

However, when I run `python manage.py celery worker --loglevel=info` I end up with:

```
OperationalError: no such table: djkombu_queue
```

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling everything, but have not been able to figure out why this table is not being created. How does one get this table created?

**EDIT**
I asked this question after looking at the other question because changing settings to:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'charts',
'social.apps.django_app.default',
'djcelery',
'kombu.transport.django',
'djcelery.transport',
```

)

**OR**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'charts',
'social.apps.django_app.default',
'djcelery',
'djcelery.transport',
)
```

Still results in:

```
Creating tables ...
Creating table django_admin_log
Creating table auth_permission
Creating table auth_group_permissions
Creating table auth_group
Creating table auth_user_groups
Creating table auth_user_user_permissions
Creating table auth_user
Creating table django_content_type
Creating table django_session
Creating table social_auth_usersocialauth
Creating table social_auth_nonce
Creating table social_auth_association
Creating table social_auth_code
Creating table celery_taskmeta
Creating table celery_tasksetmeta
Creating table djcelery_intervalschedule
Creating table djcelery_crontabschedule
Creating table djcelery_periodictasks
Creating table djcelery_periodictask
Creating table djcelery_workerstate
Creating table djcelery_taskstate
```

However the `djkombu_queue` is still missing...

Comment: Add `djcelery.transport` to installed apps and do syncdb again.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why are celery\_taskmeta and other tables not being created when running a syncdb in django?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6959702/why-are-celery-taskmeta-and-other-tables-not-being-created-when-running-a-syncdb)

Comment: it's very similar, but using the same fix did not solve my problem. See update.

Answer (score 6):

Had been stuck with the same thing since 6 days...The following finally solved it for me :-

```
pip install django-kombu
```

and then adding `djkombu` to `INSTALLED APPS` :-

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.admindocs',
    'djcelery',
    'djkombu',
    'app1',
    'app2',
    'app3',
    'app4',
)
```

Then a fresh syndb:-

```
python manage.py syncdb
```

You can check the schema with :-

```
python manage.py sqlall djkombu
```

Comment: Thank you so much @apratimankur, you avoid me 5 days of being stuck. :). The others didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

According to [current Celery documentation](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/3.1/getting-started/brokers/django.html) it is necessary to include `kombu.transport.django` into installed apps:

```
INSTALLED_APPS += ["kombu.transport.django"]
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

add djcelery.transport in installed_apps

```
INSTALLED_APPS = ('djcelery.transport', )
```

Answer (score 0):

Something has broken between various versions of Django, Django-Celery, and Kombu when trying to generate the tables.

I managed to find that Django 1.6.5, django-celery 3.1.16, and Kombu 3.0.21 WORKS.